# VS2010: c#: can't find input text component (to type text) from the VS toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, visual-studio, input

I didn't use Visual Studio for about 10 years. Let's say I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to create a simple kind of a "Hello World" application by choosing `New->Project->Windows Form Application with C#`.

The problem is I can't find something like `"html input type text"`-component  (sorry for my html :) ) from the toolbox to put on the form.  I see the checkboxes, buttons etc but I can't find the component where I can type text.

Could anybody please help me with that and what it's name?

Comment: Textbox? Are you looking for a Textbox?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for. It is so hard to jump in back after 10 years.

Comment: You might want to reconsidder... Textbox hasnt realy changed all that much in 10 years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) from the Visual Studio toolBox when the form is open